# What happened between 1996 and 2016 after they came back?

Tags: plot-explanation, jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle

After winning the [Jumanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumanji:_Welcome_to_the_Jungle) game

- Alex returns to 1996
- Fridge, Bethany, Spencer and Martha return to 2016

They all keep the memory of their adventure in the game, so what happens between 1996 and 2016? Why is Alex surprised to see them and why hasn't he tried to get in touch earlier - possibly even destroying the game so that they do not have to go through it?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer. Alex grew up.

> They all keep the memory of their adventure in the game, so what happens between 1996 and 2016?

Fridge, Bethany, Spencer and Martha were in their teens when they discovered the game. Probably born around 1996 i.e 20 years earlier.

Alex was a teenager when he discovered the game in 1996. After which 20 years has passed in real timeline of him being stuck in the game. So he was returned to his original timeline i.e 1996 when game ended. After which he grew up, now he is around 40, married and now has a kid.

> Why is Alex surprised to see them and why hasn't he tried to get in touch earlier

When Alex returned to his timeline in 1996, others were not yet born or maybe toddlers. He couldn't probably know their whereabouts. He might have moved on with his life doing college, getting married, getting a job. Life happened to Alex. He might have forgotten all about it until he saw them again in 2016.

> Why Alex didn't try to destroy the game?

This is unexplained as the time travel depicted in this movie is not he kind of one in The Back to the Future where you can alter future events by meddling with past.

Comment: *When Alex returned to his timeline in 1996, others were not yet born or maybe toodlers. He couldn't probably know their whereabouts.* Yes, but as he grew up, getting close to 2016 he could have searched for them, it was easy as they were from the same town. I will put that in the category "do not overthink the point".

Comment: @WoJ: Thanks for constructive criticism. I have updated my answer with what I actually meant. "Life happened to Alex and he might have forgotten all about it."